# Pivot in MySQL - Show first and last values depending on datetime-column

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot-table, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

after hours of researching and trying out myself I finally registered on Stackoverflow, which helped me for years by just reading. Thank you very much for this learning opportunity! I now hope to find help with a my MySQL-problem I can't get solved. I'm stuck.

**Source:** I have a table of orders made by customers.

**Output:** I want orders grouped by email adress, for every email-adress there should be a sum of total turnover, a count on orders and a row for the first order created and the last order created. *Fine until here, could be done by grouping and min() and max() functions.* Where I'm stuck: I want the IP-address of the first and last order, the first name of the first and last order and so on (see desired output further down).

**What I tried and researched on:** Groupwise max, subselect with an order inside the subselect and a group outside, several join variants.

Here is a SQLfiddle with random data and and a sql query I've build. It works sort of:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0272b/6

As an alternative to the SQL in the SQLfiddle i tried this, which works for one email-adress:

```
SELECT
    lastentry.entity_id,
    lastentry.customer_email,
    firstentry.created_at AS FirstOrder,
    lastentry.created_at  AS LastOrder,
    COUNT(lastentry.entity_id) AS TotalOrders,
    SUM(lastentry.grand_total) AS TotalTurnover,
    firstentry.entity_id,
    firstentry.remote_ip AS FirstIP,
    lastentry.remote_ip  AS LastIP
FROM
    orders lastentry
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            co1.entity_id,
            co1.customer_email,
            co1.remote_ip,
            co1.created_at
        FROM
            orders AS co1,
            (
                SELECT
                    customer_email,
                    remote_ip,
                    MIN(created_at) AS maxpop
                FROM
                    orders
                GROUP BY
                    customer_email) AS co2
        WHERE
            co2.customer_email = co1.customer_email
        AND co1.created_at = co2.maxpop ) AS firstentry
ON
    (
        lastentry.customer_email = firstentry.customer_email )
ORDER BY
    lastentry.created_at DESC,
    firstentry.created_at ASC
LIMIT 1
```

I also been trying to do a subselect or join using a subselect in a where-statement, but had no luck:

```
created_at = (SELECT MAX(t2.created_at)
    FROM orders t2
    WHERE customer_email= t1.customer_email
)
```

My actual desired output would look like the following:

```
| customer_email           | FirstOrder          | LastOrder           | TotalOrders | TotalTurnover | FirstIP       | LastIP         | FirstName | LastName |
|--------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|-------------|---------------|---------------|----------------|-----------|----------|
| darmstrong3@skype.com    | 2014-11-06 16:38:31 | 2014-11-15 11:14:42 | 2           | 116,09        | 103.132.17.9  | 153.241.73.137 | David     | David    |
| fthompson0@moonfruit.com | 2014-08-19 06:26:26 | (null)              | 1           | 1,1           | 87.217.157.91 | (null)         | Frank     | (null)   |
| jrice2@icq.com           | 2014-06-01 09:59:10 | (null)              | 1           | 95,76         | 117.4.9.206   | (null)         | Joshua    | (null)   |
| kphillips8@oracle.com    | 2015-01-30 22:49:56 | (null)              | 1           | 57,12         | 220.77.70.87  | (null)         | Kevin     | (null)   |
| lcruz5@techcrunch.com    | 2014-10-27 01:02:46 | (null)              | 1           | 90,45         | 122.38.175.17 | (null)         | Larry     | (null)   |
| scarpenter1@salon.com    | 2012-11-05 07:56:38 | 2014-06-09 21:57:20 | 3           | 163,58        | 220.75.17.164 | 203.81.207.35  | Steven    | Lousie   |
```

Any help is appreciated!

---

Questions I ask myself:

- Is this solvable in MySQL? In Excel, I could simply build a pivotal table.
- If not, can I solve it by using a stored procedure, loop through all records an skip fields if there's not more than one order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use subqueries to find the row values of the first and last orders. This assumes that the first and last orders are according to entity_id.

```
SELECT 
   customer_email, 
   COUNT(*) AS total_orders, 
   SUM(grand_total) AS total_turnover,
   (SELECT created_at FROM orders WHERE 
       entity_id = MIN(t.entity_id)) AS first_created_at,
   (SELECT created_at FROM orders WHERE 
       entity_id = MAX(t.entity_id)) AS last_created_at,
   (SELECT remote_ip FROM orders WHERE 
       entity_id = MIN(t.entity_id)) AS first_remote_ip,
   (SELECT remote_ip FROM orders WHERE 
       entity_id = MAX(t.entity_id)) AS last_remote_ip,
   (SELECT customer_firstname FROM orders WHERE 
       entity_id = MIN(t.entity_id)) AS first_customer_firstname,
   (SELECT customer_firstname FROM orders WHERE 
       entity_id = MAX(t.entity_id)) AS last_customer_firstname
FROM orders AS t
GROUP BY customer_email
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been working in this direction yesterday at some point, but then discarded the idea as I couldn't get it to work. I'll further check out your solution. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick.  It looks something like this:

```
SELECT o.entity_id, o.customer_email,
       min(created_at) AS FirstOrder, max(created_at)  AS LastOrder,
       count(*) AS TotalOrders, sum(o.grand_total) AS TotalTurnover,
       substring_index(group_concat(remote_ip order by created at), ',', 1) as first_ip,
       substring_index(group_concat(remote_ip order by created at desc), ',', 1) as last_ip
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.entity_id, o.customer_email;
```

This should work for reasonable data.  There is a configurable limit on the length of the intermediate result for `group_concat()`.

Comment: Very intersting way to solve this, thank you for the hint, Gordon! I'll play around with it to further understand this trick!